# OOP - class member pointer

Tags: c++, oop

So I have this Class A.
Now, I want to create Class B with some information from Class A. A is always created prior to B. Now I want to create an association between the two classes. Should I have a member of B point to A, or a member of A point to B? Should this decision be based on who needs to know whom or who is created first?

Comment: it's up to you. there's no right/wrong way... but obviously having a member of A point at B isn't possible until you've instantiated B.

Comment: Use interfaces and decouple the classes.

Comment: @MarcB _"but obviously having a member of A point at B isn't possible"_ It's of course possible to **have a member**, when it is initialized is something different.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the relationship between the two classes.  If b always contains information from a, then consider b inherits that information.  Also, when you instantiate a new b. It will construct an a first.

If the relationship is more has a, ie, b has its own instance of a. Then make a a member of b.

If a and b share information, or if a has to share information among several classes, then it you should cosider other patterns for a such as a singleton.